# readline doesn't return all the strings

Tags: java, readline

I am an android developer and use this code for getting String from buffer.

```
InputStream i=urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i,"UTF-8"));
while ((data = b.readLine()) != null) {
    result+=data;
}
Log.e("String",result);
```

But I can't get all string. The format of my String is json and I only get a part of it.

Comment: how long is your string? Is it possible that you get the string right but can't log it correctly?

Comment: It's very long.

Comment: You should be able to get a String of length Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Hey guy my problem was solved I just couldnot log it and I show it in a textview.thanks for your guide